# Java: Integer equality check

Tags: java, integer, equality

**Case 1:**

```
Integer number = 128;
Integer number3 = 128;
System.out.println(number == number3);
```

**Case 2:**

```
Integer number = 127;
Integer number3 = 127;
System.out.println(number == number3);
```

In this case if the value > 127 it returns false but if the value < 128 then it returns true.

**Can somebody explain why case 1 returns false and case 2 returns true?**

Comment: That's because the values under 127 being cached and using same location of storage for performance reasons in micro level. That's the reason for true in second case.

Comment: This is my favorite question after "How to compare Strings in Java?" :)

Comment: @kocko - Don't lie. Your favorite question is *is java pass-by-value or pass-by-reference*? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `Integer` class keeps a *local cache* for values between `-128` to `127`. You could increase this range as well.

Comment: it becomes 127 due to 0, zero is taken as a plus value int supports 256.

Comment: @Kandy - Umm.. Nope. Its just a cache

Comment: It also should be taken into account, that cache works only for wrapping and `valueOf()` declaration. In opposite, `new Integer(5) == new Integer(5)` would return false.

Comment: This is why if you're not sure where exactly these objects come from, use `equals()`, `compareTo()` or explicit cast.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou - I agree its always good to use `equals()` to compare objects